# Create list of lists from file python

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I'm trying to create a list of lists from a text file. The task seems easy to do but I don't know why it's not working with my code.

I have the following lines in my text file:

```
word1,word2,word3,word4
word2,word3,word1
word4,word5,word6
```

I want to get the following output:

```
[['word1','word2','word3','word4'],['word2','word3','word1'],['word4','word5','word6']]
```

The following is the code I tried:

```
mylist =[]
list =[]
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        mylist = line.strip().split(',')
        list.append(mylist)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (although `mylist =[]` is useless, and you really shouldn't use `list` as a variable name). Don't you get the desired output when you `print list`?

Comment: @MedAli It's certainly good advice to not use `list` as a variable name, but it's **not** a reserved word, otherwise it would be a syntax error to use it as a variable name (try using `for`, `while`, or `from` as variable names). `list` is the name of a built-in class, and you are free to redefine it if you really want to, but generally that's _not_ a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate like this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in open('file.txt')]
```

Comment: You should consider extending your answer to add a `with open('file.txt') as f`... it's good practice :-)

Comment: This still doesn't give me the output I'm looking for :(

Comment: @Mow1993 please post the output you are receiving currently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, if your code creating issues in your system then  if you want you can do this in one line with this :

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    print([i.strip().split(',') for i in f])
```