# Is it possible to store each line of a .txt into as a list and then use it later?

Tags: python, list, file

Im new to Python and trying to do some code on my own.
I'd like to take input from a .txt file and then store each line of that .txt into a different list.

For example, if the file has 2 lines, I want to do something like this:

.txt file:

```
blue, red, yellow, orange
city, car, airplane, dinosaur
```

python output:

```
list1 = [blue, red, yellow, orange]
list2 = [city, car, airplane, dinosaur]
```

I tried working with loops for extracting the content in form of lists, but I dont know how to store the actual results from the loop into different lists. I'm currently using the open() function to work with the files, but can't figure how to achieve this.

Thanks!

EDIT1: 23 Jun 2021

This is the work I'm using.

```py
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line.split("\n"))
```

This code prints in the console 2 lists (because the file has 2 lines). But I dont know how to store those lists in 2 differentes variables.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with: reading the file or storing the results?  Where is the code you currently have?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store into different lists?  A better choice would seem to store as a list of lists (i.e. each line as a sublist in a list).  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492510/create-list-of-lists-from-file-python)

Comment: The idea is to make a Discord bot that insults specific users. So I thought about extracting insults from a .txt where I can store them and use them later on. Instead of having a list in the code, having an updateable .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to open the file as read mode. You can handle it. A little help for you.

[Open File](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp)

If we imagine you have a lot of lines to take. You can use a loop to get all the lines step by step(You can get all lines as an array and then get them in loop or take one line in every step - I'm letting you to find this functions) and in every step you can use another loop inside of it and take the strings. To do that you should use split for every line and get array of strings belongs that line. Split functions takes a string as a parameter and returns you an array that includes all that strings. You can check it.

[Split Function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

But in your situation you want to create new array for every line in your example for 2 lines, you can take first line from file and split it and after that you can do this for other too. So you will get to 2 array includes lines.

But if you wonder how can i do this for uncertain number of line, you can use the first method that I mentioned and add all line arrays to an array at the end of every step in your first(inclusive) loop . So you will have all arrays that includes all line's string in an array. You can think like your first index of array will be your first line strings.

To imagine the figure you will get

```
all_lines=[
    [blue, red, yellow, orange],
    [city, car, airplane, dinosaur],
    [one,two,three,four]
]
```

or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will look into the things you mentioned and learn more. Thanks for your time and clear explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit more, found the answer by trial and error.
This is the code that serves my purpose

```
f = open("file.txt")
linea1 = f.readline().split(",")
linea2 = f.readline().split(",")

print(linea1)
print(linea2)
```

Output

```
linea1 = [city, building, ...]
linea2 = [hi, hello, blue ...]
```